# PostgreSQL index search on JSONB type

Tags: database, postgresql, jsonb

I have a postgres database with tables like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE state
(
    id SERIAL,
    keys JSONB NOT NULL
);
CREATE INDEX keys_idx ON state (keys);
```

With data like this (about 2.5M rows):

```
1,  ['one', 'two', 'three']
2,  ['one', 'three']
3,  ['three']
4,  ['other', 'keys', 'more']
...
```

But when i try to search for states I got seq scan (1-10 sec)

```sql
EXPLAIN ( ANALYSE )
SELECT *
FROM state s
WHERE
   s.keys <@ '["one", "two"]'
OR s.keys @> '["one", "two"]';
```

Result:

```
Seq Scan on state s  (cost=0.00..148096.55 rows=7809 width=136) (actual time=0.544..2524.739 rows=4627 loops=1)
  Filter: ((keys <@ '["one", "two"]'::jsonb) OR (keys @> '["one", "two"]'::jsonb))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 3814316
Planning time: 0.080 ms
Execution time: 2525.585 ms
```

How to improve performance of this query? Thanks.

Comment: The default `btree` operator class for `jsonb` is not very useful. [Use `USING GIN` while creating the index.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING) -- And possibly use the `jsonb_path_ops` operator class if you are not interested in the `?`, `?&` and `?|` operators (which is highly unlikely anyway in your case)

Comment: After creating gin index got same results, but ?| and ?& are useful, maybe its possible to refactor app. Thanks.